# Creating controls on surfaceview

Tags: android

Can we create any controls (listview, or button ) on surfaceview ? i want to create a custom control using listview , button and edittext. is it possible  ?

Comment: That's very strange requirement i have ever heard. Reason?

Comment: do you want to put these controls simply over the SurfaceView or do you want them to be draw drawn directly onto the SurfaceView? If so, whats the point? Explain your reasoning and we might be able to help you.

Comment: My aim is to combine all these 3 control into one and return it as single view. i know that i can put all these control in any of the layout and return that perticular layout, but i am not interested in that. i dont have much idea about using surfaceview.  or can i do as below.. i.e class mycontrol extends view { ondraw(canvas can) { //put listview , put editext , put button } } then i will pass mycontrol object into setcontentview() to display that view..